# Через несколько дней Java приложение перестает работать

Tags: docker, spring-boot

Пишу пет-приложение на Java. Spring БД Web.
Размещаю все это на сервере в отдельных докер контейнерах.
БД создается в файле docker-compose

```
  postgres-content:
    image: postgres:14.1
    container_name: content_db-v01
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5532:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=*****
    volumes:
      - /home/my-db/content_db:/var/first-prj/data/content
      - ./sql/create_db_catalog.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_db_catalog.sql
```

Для создания таблицы использую liquibase. Для работы с БД JPA.

```
spring:
  jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation: true
  jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
  datasource:
    initialization-mode: always    
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://postgres-content:5432/catalog_content?currentSchema=catalog&stringtype=unspecified
    username: content
    password: *****
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog.xml
```

Все прекрасно работает. Запускаю, день два проверяю, то что написал. Но проходит несколько дней, подключаюсь к серверу, чтобы загрузить новую версию. А приложение мое постоянно перегружается.
Просто перезапуск контейнеров не помогает.
Удаляю каталог с БД на сервере. Перегружаю и все опять работает.
Первый раз подумал, что это случайность. Но вот это случилось второй раз.

Подскажите где и как искать решение этой проблемы?
Куда смотреть?
Вот что пишет в логах:

```
19-01-2022 07:41:33.921 [main] INFO  ru.home.marketplace.contentservice.ContentServiceApplication.logStarting - Starting ContentServiceApplication v1.0-SNAPSHOT using Java 14.0.2 on c8abc4b4ef14 with PID 1 (/content.jar started by root in /)
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:33.926 [main] INFO  ru.home.marketplace.contentservice.ContentServiceApplication.logStartupProfileInfo - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:35.696 [main] INFO  org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn - Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:35.872 [main] INFO  org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 156 ms. Found 7 JPA repository interfaces.
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:36.710 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9005 (http)
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:36.730 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.log - Starting service [Tomcat]
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:36.730 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.log - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.54]
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:36.820 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/content].log - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:36.820 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.prepareWebApplicationContext - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2785 ms
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:37.014 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:38.138 [main] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
content-v01         | org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:315)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
content-v01         |   at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:313)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:771)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:763)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1318)
content-v01         |   at ru.home.marketplace.contentservice.ContentServiceApplication.main(ContentServiceApplication.java:11)
content-v01         |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
content-v01         |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
content-v01         |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
content-v01         |   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
content-v01         | Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres-content
content-v01         |   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:567)
content-v01         |   at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333)
content-v01         |   at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:648)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:231)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:95)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
content-v01         |   ... 41 common frames omitted
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:38.140 [main] WARN  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:38.146 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.log - Stopping service [Tomcat]
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:38.162 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.logMessage -
content-v01         |
content-v01         | Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
content-v01         | 19-01-2022 07:41:38.184 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure - Application run failed
content-v01         | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:771)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:763)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1318)
content-v01         |   at ru.home.marketplace.contentservice.ContentServiceApplication.main(ContentServiceApplication.java:11)
content-v01         |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
content-v01         |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
content-v01         |   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
content-v01         |   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
content-v01         | Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
content-v01         |   at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:318)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
content-v01         |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
content-v01         |   ... 27 common frames omitted
content-v01         | Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:315)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
content-v01         |   at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
content-v01         |   at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:313)
content-v01         |   ... 29 common frames omitted
content-v01         | Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres-content
content-v01         |   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:567)
content-v01         |   at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333)
content-v01         |   at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:648)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:231)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:95)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98)
content-v01         |   at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213)
content-v01         |   ... 41 common frames omitted
content-v01 exited with code 1
```

Вот логи контейнера с БД после перезапуска контейнера. До перезапуска посмотреть не догадался.

```
2022-01-19 07:39:17.471 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.1 (Debian 14.1-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2022-01-19 07:39:17.473 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2022-01-19 07:39:17.473 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2022-01-19 07:39:17.600 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-01-19 07:39:17.681 UTC [64] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-01-19 07:39:17 UTC
2022-01-19 07:39:17.721 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2022-01-19 07:42:00.441 UTC [1] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2022-01-19 07:42:00.446 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2022-01-19 07:42:00.450 UTC [1] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 70) exited with exit code 1
2022-01-19 07:42:00.454 UTC [65] LOG:  shutting down
2022-01-19 07:42:00.546 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Comment: Судя по исключениям в трассе стека, проблема с отвалившейся базе данных postgres

Comment: Но перезагрузка контейнера с БД ни чего не дает. Только полное удаление этого каталога. Как понять почему это происходит?

Comment: Что-то тут не складывается. `jdbc_url` у вас в конфигурации `localhost:5432`, а в стектрейсе `UnknownHostException: postgres-content`. Показываете не ту конфигурацию, что реально используется. Еще добавьте в вопрос конфигурацию контейнера с приложением или команду, которой запускаете приложение, если запускаете его на хосте.

Comment: Извиняюсь, я для локальной отладки меняю на local. Скопировал не глядя. На сервере, другой url. Исправил вопрос.

Comment: Возможно дело в конфиге liquibase. Стоит посмотреть его внимательней

Comment: ¿Зачем вы перезагружаете контейнер с БД? Сначала следует установить, было ли с БД что-то не так.

Comment: Дело в том что он только создает таблицы. И он это выполняет. А при последующих запусках он не должен ни чего больше делать.

Comment: Что значит перегружаю? Что вы имеете ввиду, я специально ни чего не перегружаю. Я думаю, что БД и слетела. Вопрос почему? Что могло с ней случиться. Причем это происходит второй раз

Comment: `я специально ни чего не перегружаю` и `Перегружаю и все опять работает` не стыкуются

Comment: Я же написал, что поспешил, не успел глянуть логи. Теперь, когда это повториться третий раз уже буду умнее.